# Error while building gradle in android studio

Tags: android, gradle

Information:Gradle tasks [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources]
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72311Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42311Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources FAILED
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'D:\ProgramFiles\sdk\build-tools\23.0.2\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

This is the error i am getting every time i try to build the project in  Studio. Tried all the possible solutions available in stackoverflow but not able to resolve , Please Help!!!!

Comment: The cause for the non-zero exit value i.e. the error should be earlier in the gradle output.

Comment: At times, for some reason android studio doesn't show compilation errors in the gradle console. Build the project using the `cmd` prompt. The compilation errors will be shown.

Comment: Check "D:\ProgramFiles\sdk\build-tools" directory.  And replace "23.0.2" with available build tools(You can check from sdk manager also). or You can update your build tools from SDK manager.

Comment: Run the build from a command line `gradle clean build --stacktrace`.  Then above the fail message you should see an Error from aapt.  This error is the root cause of the build failure.  The error message your showing is the generic everything failed and we have to bail message.  You need the message about what failed that was outputted before the stop everything fail message

Comment: Post your gradle and also post the full error message.

Comment: I'm not able to get the full error message Sufian Bhai ..

Answer (score 0):

Go to Build > Clean Project
then Build > Rebuild Project

if it doesn't work then go to File > Invalid Caches / Restart and select "Invalidate and Restart" button. it worked for me